# Trigonometric equation 2

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the following equation.
>   $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}\right)=-4.$$

I tried amplifying the first factor with $$\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}$$ and the second one by $$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}$$this made some simplifications but still not enough.

Comment: Hint : Rationalize each of the fraction might simplify..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first factor is
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}&=&\dfrac{(\sqrt{1-\sin x})^2-(\sqrt{1+\sin x})^2}{\sqrt{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}}\\
&=&\dfrac{(1-\sin x)-(1+\sin x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\\
&=&\dfrac{-2\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos^2x}}\\
&=&\dfrac{-2\sin x}{|\cos x|}
\end{eqnarray}
while the second factor is
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}&=&\dfrac{(\sqrt{1-\cos x})^2-(\sqrt{1+\cos x})^2}{\sqrt{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}}\\
&=&\dfrac{(1-\cos x)-(1+\cos x)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}\\
&=&\dfrac{-2\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2x}}\\
&=&\dfrac{-2\cos x}{|\sin x|}
\end{eqnarray}
The original equation becomes then
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{-2\sin x}{|\cos x|}\cdot\dfrac{-2\cos x}{|\sin x|}&=&-4\\
\dfrac{4\sin x\cos x}{|\sin x\cos x|}&=&-4\\
|\sin x\cos x|&=&-\sin x\cos x\\
|\sin2x|&=&-\sin 2x
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
$$
\pi+2k\pi \le 2x\le 2\pi+2k\pi, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z},
$$
i.e.
$$
\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \le x\le \pi+k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Observe that
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}}=\frac{1-\sin x-(1+\sin x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}=\frac{-2\sin x}{|\cos x|}$$
and

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}=\frac{1-\cos x-(1+\cos x)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}=\frac{-2\cos x}{|\sin x|}$$
Then, the given equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{4\sin x\cos x}{|\cos x \sin x|}=-4$$

Comment: Provided that $\sin{x}\cos{x}<0$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve
$$\frac{(1-\sin{x}-1-\sin{x})(1-\cos{x}-1-\cos{x})}{|\sin{x}\cos{x}|}=-4$$
or $$|\sin{x}\cos{x}|=-\sin{x}\cos{x}$$ or
$$\sin2x<0$$ or
$\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k<x<\pi+\pi k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

I will use change of variable (using the unit circle $x = \cos t$, $y = \sin t$, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$), you want $$ \left(\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+ x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)=
\left(\frac{1-y-(1+y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) \left(\frac{1-x-(1+x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\\ =\frac{(-2y)}{|x|}\frac{(-2x)}{|y|}=\pm4.$$